# Fedora 27 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++

Tags: fedora, make, libraries, c++, ld

I have Fedora 27. I am building something from source. (It is https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig-nvidia if that matters).

Make gets to linking and then fails with this message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The packages libstdc++ and libstdc++-devel are installed. Their 32-bit versions, just in case, are now also installed. I still get the message.

What can I do to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay, I found what file it's looking for using strace, and the answer was libstdc++.a , so I fixed it by installing the libstdc++-static package

Comment: Can you share the source of your installation, please?

Comment: The libstdc++-statis package is a part of Fedora. https://packages.fedoraproject.org/pkgs/gcc/libstdc++-static/